# How to forbid requests using low version of ssl?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

There is a windows 10 server in which tls1.0,ssl3 are disabled by IISCrypto for refusing weak ssl protocol from client requests. tls1.1 and tls1.2 are disabled on the client system and just ssl3 is enabled on it and will be expected any requests from client to server be refused.I'm using IIS10 and an asp mvc project website that is loaded on .I've searched and figure out there is no way to reject these request in asp mvc.The only way was using something like this `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
but doesn't work at all.By using wireshark and just look at Client Hello I realized the connection between server and client is stablished by tls1.2. I think my question is clear and no need to give code anymore.
Is there any help ?

Comment: *"tls1.1 and tls1.2 are disabled on the client system and just ssl3 is enabled on it  ... By using wireshark and just look at Client Hello I realized **the connection between server and client is stablished by tls1.2**."* - based on this the client does not use SSlv3 but TLS 1.2. Thus there is nothing to forbid, which makes your question kind of obsolete. It looks like your assumption that TLS 1.2 is disabled at the client is either wrong or does not apply to the specific client application, which might  not adhere to the system settings for example because it uses its own TLS stack.

Comment: I disabled TLS1.2 in client and now just SSlv3 is enabled.Idid it through registery and check it by internet options and IIscrypto.That was ok but I don't know why does the website on client browser load normally ?!

Comment: Again, given that you clearly say that TLS 1.2 is used by the client it means that TLS 1.2 is not disabled for this client. And again, the client might just ignore any registry settings regarding TLS versions for example if a different TLS than Windows Native (i.e. SChannel) is used. Specifically Chrome (and probably also modern Edge) uses BoringSSL and Firefox uses NSS, which both ignore the registry settings.

Comment: I got it thank you so much.